# Apache shows .htaccess for some sites

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've setting in httpd.conf to restrict access to .htaccess files for all sites and it's working for most of the sites. Unfortunately, I can see .htaccess file from web browser at one of my sites.

What can be the reason for that and how can I avoid it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the statement you are using to restrict access? Are you really really sure the file is named `.htaccess` with *one* dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard directive is:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

But there may be [issues due to case-sensitivity of your file system for example](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22750?viewlocale=en_US).